# how to compare only date part in cosmos db

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We are storing (EmployeeId,Name,LogDate) data in cosmosdb. LogDate data is Datetime and  we want to get data from cosmos where LogDate between '2018-01-15' and '2018-01-30', Means want to compare date part only.

Comment: February doesn't have 30 days so a bit of an odd question, but `WHERE LogDate >= '2018-01-15 00:00:00' AND LogDate < '2018-03-01 00:00:00'` (the latter being whichever actually existing day follows the end day) would be a way to do it in regular SQL. CosmosDB should be able to do something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the statements in the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/working-with-dates#storing-datetimes):

> Alternatively, you can store DateTimes as Unix timestamps, that is, as
>   a number representing the number of elapsed seconds since January 1,
>   1970. Azure Cosmos DB's internal Timestamp (_ts) property follows this approach. You can use the UnixDateTimeConverter class to serialize
>   DateTimes as numbers.

So, I suggest you serializing DateTimes as numbers to compare with the conditions.

You could use [User Defined Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/user-defined-functions) in sql:

UDF:

```
    function convertTime(datetime){
        datetime = datetime.replace(/-/g,'/')  
        if(datetime){
            var date = new Date(datetime);
        }else{
            var date = new Date();
        }
        time1 = date.getTime(); 
        return time1;
    }
```

SQL:

```
SELECT c.LogDate FROM c
where udf.convertTime(c.LogDate) > udf.convertTime('2018-01-15') 
and udf.convertTime(c.LogDate) < udf.convertTime('2018-02-20')
```

***Output:***

[image]

Of course, you could convert the datetime in the code instead of using UDFs.

Comment: It must be change the data storing mechanism. It is not a true answer for the question.

Answer (score 8):

I am from the CosmosDB engineering team. While Jay's answer is an alternative, you could still persist DateTimes as strings in the default ISO 8601 format and create a range index on LogDate. You should be able to do regular comparisons on DateTime like so, using Cosmos DB SQL queries:

SELECT * FROM root where root.LogDate BETWEEN '2018-01-15' and '2018-01-30'

Comment: Could I ask you to take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61110774/azure-cosmos-db-using-a-udf-seriously-slows-down-query-time

Comment: I believe Mark Brown has provided an appropriate answer already.

Comment: Thanks, Krishnan for taking a look!