# How to query cosmos records by today date with c#?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, blazor-server-side

I want to get all records where the datetime value is today.

What is the correct query string when using the c# sdk?

The property is:

```
public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
```

Not working:

```
String today = DateTime.Today.ToString();
string qs = "SELECT * FROM c where c.dueDate='"+today +"'
```

In cosmos db the json looks like this:

```
"dueDate": "2022-04-14T15:28:30.5919691+02:00"
```

Comment: [Working with Dates in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/working-with-dates)  (3 minutes to read)

Comment: @Luuk thanks, i know that site. But we are using query strings and not LinqQueryable, so i asked for the correct query string.

Comment: In your "not working" code you try to find a specific time (`today`) How high will chances be that this exact millisecond-value does exist in the database ?

Comment: @Luuk yes, so the only solutionn is to compare between 2 dates? I would use CAST but that doesn´t work with the sdk. I tought there might be a simpler way.

Comment: You might (also) have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54193358/724039

Answer (score 0):

```
var today = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm\\:ss.fffffffzzz");
var tomorrow = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm\\:ss.fffffffzzz");

string qs = "SELECT * FROM c where c.dueDate >='"+today +"' AND c.dueDate <='"+tomorrow +"'
```

or

```
string qs = "SELECT * FROM c where c.dueDate BETWEEN '"+today +"' AND '"+tomorrow +"'";
```